# How to get specific keys from an array of json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of json in my response

```
{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":51,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"log4j-2022.01.25","_type":"log4j_type","_id":"x5AWkX4BkHwsqoJA8hbA","_score":1.0,"_source":{"@timestamp":"2022-01-25T11:55:07.221Z","commands":"wc,trim,uniq,sort","message":"2022-01-25 17:25:06 wc,trim,uniq,sort sharon","@version":"1","host":"sharon","time":"2022-01-25 17:25:06","username":"sharon","path":"/home/sharon/Log/Logging.log"}},
[{"_index":"log4j-2022.01.25","_type":"log4j_type","_id":"yJAXkX4BkHwsqoJAAhZi","_score":1.0,"_source":{"@timestamp":"2022-01-25T11:55:11.224Z","commands":"wc,sort,trim,uniq","message":"2022-01-25 17:25:10 wc,sort,trim,uniq sharon","@version":"1","host":"sharon","time":"2022-01-25 17:25:10","username":"sharon","path":"/home/sharon/Log/Logging.log"}},
...]}}
```

I just want the username and commands field from the each json object. I've fetched the data using axios. How can I do it?

```
const query = {
    query: {
      match_all: {},
    },
    _source: ["time"],
  };
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:9200/log4j-2022.01.25/_search", query)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
```

Much appreciated

Comment: There are two opening `[` and one closing `]`. Are you sure the second opening `[` is correct? Can you fix?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a `[` floating in your JSON that does not belong there. If this is indeed the case, then this code would retrieve the username and commands properties:

```
let result = res.data.hits.hits.map(
    ({_source: {commands, username}}) => ({commands, username})
);
```

For the given sample data this will set `result` to:

```
[
  { "commands": "wc,trim,uniq,sort", "username": "sharon" }
  { "commands": "wc,sort,trim,uniq", "username": "sharon" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gave me the expected output. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
const { hits } = res.data.hits

const remapped = hits.map((element) => ({commands: element._source.commands, username: element._source.username}))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gave me the expected output. Much appreciated